# Installing pywin32 on MSYS2

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com, msys2

I am trying to uae win32com api with MSYS2 for the purpose of having an MSYS2 portable development environment for our team. I tried installing via pip, wheel, pacman but failed. Anyone with idea if it is possible at all? Or any alternative to use win32api with python on msys? Building form source? or Via C language.... etc.